# from MRC to ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, automatic-ref-counting

Sometimes, before the arc was introduced, I wasn't using the @property declaration and use just iVar like follow:

```
//Foo.h
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
    NSString *str;
}

- (id)initWithStr:(NSString *)newStr;
..
//Foo.m

- (id)initWithStr:(NSString *)newStr
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        str = [newStr retain];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   [str release];
   [super dealloc];
}
...
```

How to implement something like this with ARC if I don't want to use `@property` declaration?

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: just don't use ARC if your don't want to use @property etc. You can exlcude the fies where you've done stuff like this from being put under ARC. Much simpler than trying to make a square peg fit a round hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARC just works:

```
- (id)initWithStr:(NSString *)newStr
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        str = newStr;
    }
    return self;
}
```

... and no dealloc :)

Comment: No. str is strong by default under ARC. So it will be retained.

Comment: @Bourne before asking this question I had tested this situation and ref count equal to 1 not 2

Comment: @tikhop sorry, didn't realize that. I take back that comment.

Answer (score -1):

Declare str in .h file.

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *str;
```

You can synthesize this variable in . m file like `@sythesize str;`

You can use `self.str` for assigning or getting `str`.
For more details read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Comment: I don't want to use @property, I want use just iVar